# TypeError: cannot parse from 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse a lot of xml files and load the data into the database. Running the following:

```
import os 
from lxml import etree
path = 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/python/python-parsing/data'
filename = os.listdir(path)
tree = etree.parse(filename)
test = tree.xpath('///p[@name="bName"]')
print ("".join(test))
```

Result:

```
Desktop\python\python-parsing\parser.py", line 6, in <module>
tree = etree.parse(filename)
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3435, in lxml.etree.parse
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1863, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
TypeError: cannot parse from 'list'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, are you facing an error? Maybe post about your error message and what steps you have taken to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `os.listdir(path)` returns a list of all files in your data folder, even if there is only one file. As such, you need to get the filename you want in this list before parsing it.